# AJAX loading of XML for jQuery Change

Tags: xml, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to use AJAX to load my xml data into jQuery change to display certain values when the specific item is selected. I can get the cities to come up the change selector, but I can't figure out how to get the right information to output and change with the selector. Right now I just have the last value outputting no matter which item is selected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var cityID;
var city;
var amt;


$(document).ready(function() {


$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "data/precipData.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: makeItRain
});
});


function makeItRain(xml) {

$(xml).find("Row").each(function(){

cityID = $(this).attr("id");
city = $(this).find("city").text();
amt = $(this).find("amt").text();

$('<option id="' + cityID + '">' + city + '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');
console.log('appending');

$(".selectCity").change(function() {

    $('option:selected', this).attr('id');
        $(".name").html(city);
        console.log('city');
        $(".ammount").html(amt);
        console.log('amt');
  });


});
};
</script>
```

XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Document>
     <!--Created with XmlGrid Free Online XML Editor (http://xmlgrid.net)-->
     <Row id="1">
           <city>Albuquerque, NM</city>
           <amt>0.69</amt>
     </Row>
     <Row id="2">
           <city>Arlington, TX</city>
           <amt>13.78</amt>
     </Row>
     <Row id="3">
           <city>Atlanta, GA</city>
           <amt>20.6</amt>
     </Row>
 </Document>
```

Comment: Can you provide us with a small version of your XML file for testing?

Comment: Hey, I've added a brief version of my XML.

Comment: I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/XduyF/) for you.  I'll poke at a solution.

Comment: Updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/hmbZK/

Comment: I don't really understand what you've done. I'm looking to get the data from the XML file to display when that city is selected.

Comment: That Fiddle is just your original code put into something that JSFiddle can use.  It's not a fix.  Check out the answer below for a fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few changes.  Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PacmanBits/NwRjp/1/).  First I'll post the entire updated code, then we'll go over everything change by change.

```
$(function()
{
    $(xml).find("Row").each(function()
    {
        cityID = $(this).attr("id");
        city = $(this).find("city").text();
        amt = $(this).find("amt").text();

        $('<option value="' + amt + '" id="' + cityID + '">' + city + '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');
        console.log('appending');
    });

    $(".selectCity").change(function()
    {
        var sel = $(this).children("option:selected");
        city = sel.text();
        amt = sel.attr("value");
        $(".name").html(city);
        $(".ammount").html(amt);
    });
});
```

1. You'll notice that I've moved the `.change()` listener outside of
   the `.each()` function.  JQuery has a handy (albeit occasionally
   obstructing) ability to attach multiple functions to the same
   listener.  This is *super* handy when you're working on a large
   project, with multiple contributors who may all want to attach
   listeners to the same object.  In **this** case, however, attaching
   a new listener handler to `.selectCity` on each iteration of the
   loop will leave you with nothing but a lot of redundant listeners;
   and so we move it outside of the `.each()`.
2. `$('<option value="' + amt + '" id="' + cityID + '">' + city +
   '</option>').appendTo('.selectCity');`

   (This is the important one) you declared the variable `city` and `amt` at the top scope.  These variables will be persistent, so
   that in any case after the finish of the loop (for example, when a
   user selects an option) they will be equal to the last values set
   (the last values found by the loop).  There needs to be some way to
   associate each of these values with each `option` tag.  Fortunately,
   the `option` tag has a handy attribute called `value`.  `value` is a
   small amount of data that can be attached to the `option` in case
   the display value isn't adequate.  Now, both `city` and `amt` are
   directly associated with the `option` element.
3. `var sel = $(this).children("option:selected");`

   You almost had the `option:selected` selector used properly, but you
   forgot to set it to a variable.  I've set it to the variable `sel`;
   you can see how this gives us easy access to the selected `option`.
4. `city = sel.text();` `amt = sel.attr("value");`
   `$(".name").html(city);` `$(".ammount").html(amt);`

   Finally, we get the desired data from the `option` element and set
   it accordingly.

Comment: No problem!  Hope it helped!